# Using a switch statement to construct a Regular Expression in Swift 3

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, swift, swift3

I've created a function that generates a `RegularExpression` in Swift 3.0. I'm close to what I want, but the **backslash** is causing me a lot of trouble.

I've looked at [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) and I thought changing the "\" to `\u{005C}` or `u{005C}` would resolve the issue, but it doesn't.

Here's the array I'm feeding my regex generation function:

```
var letterArray = ["a","","a","","","","","","",""]
```

Here's the relevant portion of my method:

```
var outputString = String()

// getMinimumWordLength returns 3
let minimumWordLength = getMinimumWordLength(letterArray: letterArray)
// for the array above, maximumWordLength returns 10
let maximumWordLength = letterArray.count

var index = 0

for letter in letterArray {
    if index < minimumWordLength {
        if letter as! String != "" {
            outputString = outputString + letter.lowercased
        } else {
            // this puts an extra \ in my regex
            outputString = outputString + "\\w" // first \ is an escape character, 2nd one gets read
            // this puts an extra backslash in, too
            // outputString = outputString + "\u{005C}w"
        }
    }
    index += 1
}

outputString = outputString + ("{\(minimumWordLength),\(maximumWordLength)}$/")

return outputString
```

My desired output is:

```
a\wa{3,10}$/
```

My actual output is:

```
a\\wa{3,10}$/
```

If anyone has suggestions what I'm fouling up, I welcome them. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but your code gives the desired output. The only I made was add the round brackets after `lowercased`: `outputString = outputString + letter.lowercased()`

Comment: Add `print(outputString)` and see what you get. (I needed the fix shown by Code Different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When string is printed in debugger, escape character will be displayed. When it is displayed for user, it will not.
[image]

Comment: Ugh! I knew it would be simple, but jeez! Thank you! I'm presently debugging and didn't use a print statement b/c it's going through a bajillion records.